# HowlerJS work on the server side on nodejs

Tags: node.js, howler.js

Despite knowing that HowlerJS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler) is a great client site music executing tool, I really need it to run on the server side, just playing music directly from the server via external Linux hardware.

Does anyone know if hawing Howler directly working on the server side is somehow possible via other dependencies?

Any help would be highly appriciated!!

```
const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 4000;
const app = express();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const { Howl, Howler } = require("howler");

let file = new Howl({
  src: "./testFilesMP3/Little Lies.mp3",
  autoplay: true,
});

file.play();


app.use("/schedules", require("./controllerFunctions/scheduler.js"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("APP IS ONLINE");
});
```